# How Java (JVM?) knows the director of the package

Tags: java, package

I wonder how java (JVM?) knows the directory of the package when I type e.g "import java.awt.*". 
The thing is that when I create package, the java file that imports class from this package needs to be in the same folder with the package directory and needs to pass the directory after import statement. In the other hand when e.g "java.awt.*" is imported, directory of importing file doesn't matter. 
Please tell me how it works.

Regards

Comment: Do a web search for [`java class loading`](https://www.google.com/#q=java+class+loading) if you want to learn how it works.

Comment: Read up on what the [classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) is.  This is a fundamental Java concept; you should not attempt to develop in Java until you have a solid grasp of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are stored literally in directories. In your file explorer, look at your workspace's `src` folder. The packages you can't find there are in your system java library. which is in your JAVA_HOME I think